# How to select a specific entry in a List from DB?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

How can I query for a specific project if I have 2 parameters `username` and `projectname`? Especially, what's wrong with the following query?

```
class Person {
   private String name;
   private List<Project> projects;
}

class Project {
   private String projectname;
}
```

Query:

```
SELECT Project FROM Person p WHERE p.name := username AND p.projects.projectname =: projectname
```

Result:

```
illegal attempt to dereference collection [person0_.name.projects] with element property reference [projectname]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are doing operations on collection of your pojo ,You have to eagerly load the collection before doing on operations on it.

Try(Didn't test it)

```
SELECT Project FROM Person p left join fetch p.projects as projs WHERE
                        p.name := username AND  projs.projectname =: projectname
```

Please [refer association joins in HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)